# Getting error in following c code [Segmentation fault]

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf, format-specifiers

Getting segmentation fault when using `*s` instead of `char s`.
if I change `*s` to `s` I get error named `char` pointer to integer.Please help me find the error.I also Googled but was not able to get it corrected.

```
#include<stdio.h>


main()
{
char *s,o,a,b,j[20];
printf("code generation\n----------------------");
printf("Enter the code:\n");
scanf("%s",j);
int c=1;
while(c==1){
        o=j[1];
        a=j[0];
        b=j[2];

        switch(o){
        case '+':
               s="ADD";
                break;
            case '-':
                s="SUB";
                break;
            case '*':
                s="MUL";
                break;
            case '/':
                s="DIV";
                break;
            case '=':
                s="MOV";
                break;
            default:
                s="INV";
        }
        printf("Code Generated:%s %s , %s\n",s,a,b);

}



 }
```

Comment: @AlterMann I just edit and fixed it

Comment: Your code exhibits Undefined Behavior if 1)The user enters something longer than 19 characters 2) If the user enters just one character and 3)See @SouravGhosh's answer

Comment: C has the feature of allowing more than one char in names, mainly to make them autodocumented.  Please use more descriptive names next time you ask something.

Answer (score 2):

For a definition like

```
char *s,o,a,b,j[20];
```

- `s` is of type `char *`.
- `o`, `a`, `b` are of type `char`
- `j` is of type `char [20]` (array).

So, you need to change your code

```
printf("Code Generated:%s %s , %s\n",s,a,b);
```

to

```
printf("Code Generated:%s %c , %c\n",s,a,b);
```

as the correct format specifier for a `char` is `%c`.

*Suggestion:*

1. Always prefer `int main(void)` over `main()`.
2. Enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them.

Related reading: From `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.1, `fprintf()` function (emphasis mine)

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. **If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.**

And, a note about [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Good answer, there is a [related question](http://c-faq.com/decl/charstarws.html) in the C-FAQ

Comment: @CoolGuy  § is called selection symbol. use  "&#167;"  [hope this instance prints properly.] in HTML . :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit off topic, but this line :

```
 printf("Code Generated:%s %s , %s\n",s,a,b);
```

`a` and `b` are not strings (=`char*`), but chars.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `a` and `b` are character variables not a string.
Change your `printf` into like this.

`%c` is format specifier for character.

```
printf("Code Generated:%s %c , %c\n",s,a,b);
```

You have to allocate the memory for pointer variable `char *s`. And assign the value to that variable using `strcpy`.

```
s=malloc(30);
strcpy(s,"ADD");
```

Comment: There is no need to allocate memory for `s`.